AdaptiveCard v1.3 weirdness in M365 / SharePoint Online Search Results
I am working with M365 / SharePoint Online.  We are successfully using an Agent as a Data Source to index content on a legacy site (not on a Microsoft stack at all), and add index items to the search index - that's all fine and works as intended.
I am having issues correctly coding a JSON template to use as custom Result Item for the relevant data source.  As you can see from the screen shot below we are able to render results but not all code works as expected.
I do not have access to a proper dev environment or advanced tooling, nor system access.  I have to code in Notepad and provide it to a engineer who has system access.  This works but is slow.
Here's a screen shot of the results we get using the code, also below; I have some specific questions at the bottom...

I am using this JSON:
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.3",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "auto",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "url": "https://searchuxcdn.azureedge.net/designerapp/images/HtmlCodeIcon.svg",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "center",
                            "size": "small"
                        }
                    ],
                    "horizontalAlignment": "center"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "ColumnSet",
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "auto",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "text": "[${Title}](${URL})",
                                            "weight": "bolder",
                                            "size": "medium",
                                            "maxLines": 3,
                                            "color": "accent"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "spacing": "none"
                                }
                            ],
                            "spacing": "small"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "[${URL}](${URL})",
                            "spacing": "small",
                            "weight": "bolder",
                            "color": "good"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Container",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Last Modified ${DCDatemodified}",
                                    "spacing": "small",
                                    "$when": "${!empty(DCDatemodified)}"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Last Modified {{DATE(${LastModifiedDateTime})}}",
                                    "spacing": "small",
                                    "$when": "${empty(DCDatemodified)}"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Control 0: ${DCDatemodified} __ ${LastModifiedDateTime}",
                                    "spacing": "small"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Last Modified 2a {{formatDateTime(DATE(${LastModifiedDateTime}),'', 'en-NZ')}}",
                                    "spacing": "small",
                                    "$when": "${!empty(LastModifiedDateTime)}"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Last Modified 2b {{formatDateTime(DATE(${LastModifiedDateTime}),'dd MMMM yyyy','')}}",
                                    "spacing": "small",
                                    "$when": "${!empty(LastModifiedDateTime)}"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Last Modified 2c {{formatDateTime(${LastModifiedDateTime},'', 'en-NZ')}}",
                                    "spacing": "small",
                                    "$when": "${!empty(LastModifiedDateTime)}"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Last Modified 2d {{formatDateTime(${LastModifiedDateTime},'dd MMMM yyyy','')}}",
                                    "spacing": "small",
                                    "$when": "${!empty(LastModifiedDateTime)}"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Last Modified 2c {{if(equals(1, 1), 'yes', 'no')}}",
                                    "spacing": "small"
                                }
                            ],
                            "spacing": "small"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "${Keywords}",
                            "maxLines": 2,
                            "wrap": true,
                            "spacing": "small"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "${description}",
                            "maxLines": 2,
                            "wrap": true,
                            "spacing": "small"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "FileType: ${FileType}",
                            "spacing": "small"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "FileType 1: {{tolower(${FileType})}}",
                            "spacing": "small"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "FileType 2: {{toLower(${FileType})}}",
                            "spacing": "small"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "FileType 3: {{toUpper(${FileType})}}",
                            "spacing": "small"
                        }
                    ],
                    "spacing": "medium"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "$data": {
        "${DCDatemodified}": "2019-09-25T06:08:39Z,SHORT",
        "${description}": "Marketing team at Contoso.., and looking at the Contoso Marketing..",
        "${Keywords}": "Test 001 - v19",
        "${URL}": "https://modernacdesigner.azurewebsites.net",
        "${Title}": "Contoso Marketing Analysis - Q3 FY18"
    }
}

I have been using this page for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/adaptive-expressions/adaptive-expressions-prebuilt-functions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#date  I realise it is documentation for bots but I am assuming that basic Adaptive Card syntax is similar enough.  Certainly I have been able to get functions like empty() working as expected.
Questions
How to use formatDateTime?  As you can see the JSON is rendered.
Same for the if and toLower functions, which I would also like to use.
I am puzzled because "text": "Last Modified ${DCDatemodified}" and "text": "Last Modified {{DATE(${LastModifiedDateTime})}}" both render correctly, but as you can see the syntax is wildly different.
I'm also puzzled that the DATE function only works when full caps (in contrast to the documentation) - in contrast to functions like empty which need to be lower case.

${formatDateTime(DCDatemodified, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/date-time-values#custom-format-strings
The format string hh:mm:ss tt returns the 12 hour format:
formatDateTime('2009-06-15T13:45:30', 'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt') //
enter code here
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.3",
"body": [
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "${if(condition, 'True Text', 'False Text')}"
},
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "${toLower(yourStringProperty)}"
}
]
}

The answer lacks context and explanation. Please provide more details on how this code addresses the issue with AdaptiveCard v1.3 in M365/SharePoint Online Search Results.
